# Forgotten location of linux startup instruction

Tags: linux, raspbian

I have an instrument control program running which presents a webpage for user input. It's on a little raspberry pi running raspbian. I have, alas, and stupidly, forgotten which of the many available methods I used to get the python file to run on startup. And I now need to change it.

I can trace the process number (from "top") and the command line executed ("ps ") but I cannot find from where this is being executed.

Any help would be very useful.

Comment: Look in system log; or see if it has a systemctl status?

Comment: *forgotten which of the many available methods I used* - there's not so many that you can't check them all, is there?

Comment: Check crontab -l first. If it's listed there, use crontab -e to change it.